# Keep Group on one page if possible not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am building a SSRS report in 2012.

I have a tablix that has one grouping and one detail. There are 5 rows in the tablix, 4 of which are displaying group level information, or the headers for the detail, and then one detail row itself.

In the Row Groups section I have the following layout

```
[ (Group1)
  (Static)
  (Static)
  (Static)
    - (Detail)
  (Static)
  (Static)
```

My goal is to, whenever possible keep all the rows for a group on the same page. If I can fit about 16 rows on a page, as long as I have about less than 12 detial rows I should be able to fit them on one page long with the 4 group level rows.

I have gone to the "Row Groups" section and click on each of the 7 items and selected `KeepTogether = True`. I also selected the first two static rows and the last two static rows and set them to `KeepWithGroup = After`. I could not set the middle static row to `KeepWithGroup = After` because I would get the following error when saving: `The grouping 'Group1' has an invalid TablixMember. A TablixMember that is dynamic (i.e., has a Group specified) or has dynamic descendants must have the KeepWithGroup property set to "None".`

What else can I do to keep each group on the same page when possible?

Answer (score 0):

Static tablix members will chain together KeepWithGroup=After and KeepWithGroup=Before until they reach a dynamic sibling tablix member and then stick there. Setting all your rows to "keep after" means that the first two rows will try to stay with the dynamic detail line, and the last two rows will try to stay with the first two rows of the next group and their dynamic detail line.

In this case you want to set KeepWithGroup=After on the first two static rows and KeepWithGroup=Before on the last two static rows.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting `Tablix Properties` >> `Keep together on one page if possible` to true (checked) and do uncheck `new page` for `group`

[image]
[image]

Comment: When I do that, I every group on it's own page. I want more than one group to be on each page, except when breaking to the next page will prevent splitting the group between two pages.

Comment: Modified answer - In `Group Properties` uncheck the `Page Break options`.

Comment: I tried that too and it didn't work. It would split the group onto different pieces of paper when I printed it.

Comment: Don't think there is an easy way to do what you require. You might want to try doing some custom code to split the pages